# Android Activity Displaying Random Users

Tags: java, android, mobile, webview

I am trying to create an app that has an **activity** screen that allows a user to see random users who have downloaded the app as well. I failed short finding information/tutorials related to the topic. I understand there will be manipulation of profile data via php/mysql. An example of what the functionality I am looking for would be instagram's search page that shows a **grid of random profiles**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the  **Firebase Realtime Database.**
In case you don't know it, Firebase Database is an online database it handles most of the work for you. Simply make your users enter their information(Name,Profile picture,Age etc...) and then retreive the user data. Check out the [Firebase database documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for more info.
There are also other alternatives.